# Create n-level multidimensional array in PHP from String

Tags: php, arrays

To get the right position I have to access in a tree array I'm working on a solution to bring an exploded string (with numeric keys, separated by "." (dot) - like in an register) to an array ...

```
$string = '1.3.2.5';
```

so the returning value should be an array with

```
$array[1][3][2][5] = 'x';
```

where x can hold any data or be empty

Comment: Do you want to read or write the array tree? Or do both?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty solution using [eval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). I need to quote Rasmus Lerdorf here:

> If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong
>   question.

So, no, I am not happy with this answer, but it does work. Keep in mind that if the input comes from the users you might give them unwanted control over your server. It is very easy to do:

`$test = 'x; rmdir($_SERVER["HOME"]);';`. *Do not use this on your server!*

So be careful with this.

```
<?php

$string = '1.3.2.5';
$test   = 'x';
$array  = [];

function setArray($address,$value)
{
    global $array;
    eval('$array['.str_replace('.','][',$address).'] = $value;');
}

function getArray($address)
{
    global $array;
    eval('$value = $array['.str_replace('.','][',$address).'];');
    return $value;
}

setArray($string,$test);

echo getArray($string);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Note that this will work with any address length > 1. Also note that you can overwrite a complete tree, accidentally, if you use a short address.

Who can find a good solution without `eval()`?